# Display Spanish characters with accents properly

Tags: excel, macos, utf-8

The file I am working on has everything written in Spanish. The format is .sav. What I wanna do is to open it on JMP, export to Excel with .csv format. I am using Mac with running OS Sierra.

Here is the problem. I surely opened the file with utf-8 on JPM but there are some corrupted characters. So I changed the default language of Mac to Spanish and it did not work. I also exported the file from JMP to texteditor with the corruption remaining, duplicate the file with utf-8, and import on Excel. It did not work as well. Changing to utf-16 was one of my attempts and did not work at all. I used Numbers instead of Excel, but this also failed.

What else I can do to display the characters properly?
FYI, the file is taken from http://evaluacion.oportunidades.gob.mx:8010/EVALUACION/en/eval_cuant/p_bases_cuanti.php
Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What **font** are you using ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I am using Calibri. Does font matter to this problem?